# Is there a way to set up the build order in a JAVA project on VSCode?

Tags: java, maven, visual-studio-code

Simple question here but could not found it anywhere else.

Eclipse has this feature in Preferences > General > Workspace > Build where you can set the projects build order. Is there any way to do it on VS Code?

Using Maven.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using a buildsystem like Grade, Maven, or Ant? Please [edit] to clarify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

##### It seems that vscode currently does not have such an interface feature to set the build order of Java projects.

*eclipse*
[image]

For more Java project management, you can check [this link](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-project). If you have a need, you can file a report on [GitHub](https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-java/issues/new) to get a response from the official folks, maybe they will consider adding this.

In addition, the same effect can be achieved by modifying [*pom.xml*](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html) in maven. Pay attention to follow the rules of dependency resolution and version specifications, otherwise the build will fail.